# TFS can not restore nuget from Tfs Packages(Azure Artifacts) in linux

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to build my .net core application using linux's build agent. But if my nuget is hosted in tfs packages or Azure Artifacts, it can't be restored.

Always get an error when using the dotnet step to restore nuget

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.300/NuGet.targets(121,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source http://tfsServer/ProjectCollection/_packaging/guid/nuget/v3/index.json.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.300/NuGet.targets(121,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

[Nuget Task Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRC1R.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X11T.png)

**I Try:**

Refer to the practices mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider to install the plugin in the linux agent and specify the environment variable VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS at compile time.
But no effect.

If you are not using nuget of tfs itself.
A nuget built with a blank site referenced by nuget.server can be restored normally.

Tfs Server version: Tfs 2018 Update2
Build Agent Linux Server: centos 7.2
Agent version:  2.131

Comment: There is currently no update, and subsequent attempts will be made to upgrade TFS to Azure Devops Server 2019U1, but there is currently no action.
But no matter how this problem is solved under TFS2018?

Answer (score 0):

According to the similar error in this link: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6902

You should be able to use a credential provider as mentioned. Please also make sure  you have met all prerequisites for it

- **MSBuild on Windows**: Install Visual Studio version 15.9-preview1 or
  later to get the required version of msbuild (15.8.166.59604 or
  later).
- **NuGet**: NuGet(.exe) on the command line version 4.8.0.5385 or later is
  required.
- **dotnet**: dotnet SDK version 2.1.400 or later is required on Windows.

Besides, your build agent version 2.131 is too old. Please upgrade  [azure-pipelines-agent](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases) to latest and try again.

Comment: I can do it under Windows, but it can't be done under Linux, so it should be irrelevant.
Windows can use the nuget task for the .net framework to restore correctly.

Comment: Hi Leolaw, thanks for your update. Your task looks properly. For this scenario, it may related environment issue, suggest you directly remote to Linux build agent. And use net core command line to restore the packages and build, check if this works. It will narrow down the issue.